# How does the Richards' differential equation (RDE) change, if I add the lower asymptote in the generalised logistic function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, partial-differential-equations, logistic-regression

### The Question

Let's consider the Richards' differential equation (RDE) as written here below, from Wikipedia:

[image]

How does the RDE change if I add the lower asymptote "A" in the generalised logistic function as follows?

$$
Y(t) = \frac{K}{(1+Qe^{-\alpha\nu(t-t_0)})^{1/\nu}} + A
$$

### My Attempt

In order to add the lower asymptote "A" in the RDE, I first tried to solve the RDE, getting the generalised logistic function:

$$
Y'(t) = \alpha Y \biggl(1- \biggl(\frac{Y}{K} \biggr)^\nu \biggr)
$$

$$
\alpha \int_{t_0}^t dt = \int \frac{dY}{Y \biggl(1- \biggl(\frac{Y}{K} \biggr)^\nu \biggr)}
$$

$$
\alpha (t-t_0) = ln|Y| - \frac{ln\biggl|1-\biggl(\frac{Y}{K}\biggr)^\nu\biggr|}{\nu}
$$

$$
\nu \alpha (t-t_0) = ln|Y|^\nu - ln\biggl|1-\biggl(\frac{Y}{K}\biggr)^\nu\biggr|
$$

$$
- \nu \alpha (t-t_0) = - ln|Y|^\nu + ln\biggl|1-\biggl(\frac{Y} {K}\biggr)^\nu\biggr| + C
$$

$$
- C - \nu \alpha (t-t_0) = ln\left| \frac{1-\biggl(\frac{Y} {K}\biggr)^\nu}{Y^\nu} \right|
$$

$$
\pm e^{- C} e^{- \nu \alpha (t-t_0)} = \frac{1-\biggl(\frac{Y} {K}\biggr)^\nu}{Y^\nu}
$$

$$
\pm e^{- C} e^{- \nu \alpha (t-t_0)} = \biggl( 1-\biggl(\frac{Y} {K}\biggr)^\nu \biggr) \frac{1}{Y^\nu}
$$

$$
\pm e^{- C} e^{- \nu \alpha (t-t_0)} = \frac{1}{Y^\nu} - \frac{1}{K^\nu}
$$

I use: $W = \pm e^{- C}$

$$
\frac{1}{K^\nu} + W e^{- \nu \alpha (t-t_0)} = \frac{1}{Y^\nu}
$$

$$
\frac{1 + K^\nu W e^{- \nu \alpha (t-t_0)}}{K^\nu} = \frac{1}{Y^\nu}
$$

$$
Y^\nu = \frac{K^\nu}{1 + K^\nu W e^{- \nu \alpha (t-t_0)}}
$$

I use: $Q = K^\nu W$

$$
Y^\nu = \frac{K^\nu}{1 + Q e^{- \nu \alpha (t-t_0)}}
$$

$$
Y = \frac{K}{\biggl( 1 + Q e^{- \nu \alpha (t-t_0)}\biggr)^{1/\nu}}
$$

**Any suggestions or ideas to get the RDE, using the lower asymptote "A" in the generalised logistic function, as follows?**

$$
Y(t) = \frac{K}{(1+Qe^{-\alpha\nu(t-t_0)})^{1/\nu}} + A
$$

**Note: I also found something close to my case, but I am not able to combine it with the exponent $1/\nu$ in my generalised logistic function. Ideas?** (reference: Oliver, F. (1969). Another Generalisation of the Logistic Growth Function. Econometrica, 37(1), 144-147. doi:10.2307/1909213):
[image]

Comment: Hi guys, any idea so far ?!