# How to solve the Richard differential equation? (analytical solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I would like to solve the Richard differential equation, i.e. getting the the generalised logistic function. I tried to calculate it,

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = \beta y \biggl( 1 - \biggl( \frac{y}{L} \biggr)^a \biggr)
$$

getting:

$$
\beta (t - t_0) = \int \frac{dy}{y\big(1-\big(\frac{y}{L}\big)^a\big)} 
$$

but I am stuck at that integral. Any idea how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some context regarding the Richard differential equation, and why you wish to solve it (mathematical reasons, that is). Providing such context will help you improve your question so it can attract more people. At the moment your question has too little participation (I am not an integrals person, so I can't help unfortunately) but adding more details will surely be beneficial to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

$$
\frac{dy}{y\left(1-\left(\frac yL\right)^a\right)} = \frac{dy}{y}+\frac{\left(\frac{y}{L}\right)^{a-1}dy}{L \left(1-\left(\frac{y}{L}\right)^a\right)}
$$

Comment: thank you very much, very kind!

Comment: For those people who are interested: I was able to go through it and I derived the generalised logistic function from the Richards differential equation here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4024391/edited-how-does-the-richards-differential-equation-rde-change-if-i-add-t
...However, in the same post I asked an additional question..